# A RenderFlex overflowed by 58 pixels on the bottom. Flutter GridView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I need to create a list of elements to do a "wikipedia" style page, like a documentation with images and texts. This is my code and i got a yellow and black strip with "A RenderFlex overflowed by 58 pixels on the bottom.".

```
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: Scrollbar(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: classe.content.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 1,
                  ),

                  shrinkWrap: true,

                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => BuildContent(
                    content: classe.content[index],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Remove `shrinkWrap: true` from your `GridView.builder`

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your *Column* like this :

```dart
SingleChildScrollView
  child: SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Column(/*...*/),
  ),
)
```

Comment: I got an error
```RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#5d066 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'```

Comment: Does it work if you switch places for _SizedBox_ and _SingleChildScrollView_? **PS**: I edited my answer.

Comment: Well... Same error

Comment: The problem should be coming from `BuildContent`, because I removed it so I can test your code and the only error I  got was from the `Scrollbar`, so I removed it and the code worked fine.